# Angular Form - I can access the value of a textbox on a form with a template variable on the textbox but not any other way

Tags: angular

This works:

```
    <form action="javascript:;" (ngSubmit)="save(textBox1Control.value, textBox2Control.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Text Box 1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textBox1" required ng-maxlength="100" #textBox1Control />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>New password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textBox2" required ng-maxlength="100" #textBox2Control />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group action-button-row">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

But not this:

```
    <form action="javascript:;" #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Text Box 1:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textBox1" required ng-maxlength="100" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>New password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="textBox2" required ng-maxlength="100" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group action-button-row">
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I would have expected the argument passed to the save() function in this example to be { textBox1: "value1", textBox2: "value2" }, with value1 and value2 being what I entered in the textboxes.

I also tried using ngModel (Angular's preferred way anyway, with variables defined in the component class) and using reactive forms (with ReactiveFormsModule imported into the module) but neither of those worked either.

Yes, I have FormsModule imported.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the guide of angular that explains the template driven approach: https://angular.io/guide/forms

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}

  save(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Text Box 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textBox1" required ng-maxlength="100" ngModel/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>New password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="textBox2" required ng-maxlength="100" ngModel/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group action-button-row">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```